# Variable with same name as type gives no compilation error when placed in function, struct or class

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, typedef

Given the Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef int Integer;
Integer Integer = 1234;

int main() {
    std::cout <<  "Integer: " << Integer;
}
```

Compiling the code with the [gcc 11.2 Compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/1rT7co8hc) will result in compilation errors:

```
error: 'Integer Integer' redeclared as different kind of entity
    4 | Integer Integer = 1234;
      |         ^~~~~~~

note: previous declaration 'typedef int Integer'
    3 | typedef int Integer;
      |             ^~~~~~~

In function 'int main()':
error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
    7 |         std::cout <<  "Integer: " << Integer;
      |                                             ^
```

However, changing the code to:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef int Integer;

int main() {
    Integer Integer = 1234;
    std::cout <<  "Integer: " << Integer;
}
```

will not result in a compilation error. 
I tried using the
[gcc 11.2](https://godbolt.org/z/PW39MPMds),
[clang 12.0.1](https://godbolt.org/z/PqzEPvbor) and MSVC 19.29 Compiler and all failed at the first version but allowed the second one. 
Why does the second version work while the first one fails?

Comment: Completely setting aside the question if this is a compiler bug, or whether or not any of this is valid C++: why would someone want to do this in the first place? Inside or outside of a function?

Comment: I would never write something like that. However, today I encountered this problem in a company I am currently working in. Someone named their variable the same way as its type and while it worked in a function it didn't when declared in the global scope.

Comment: `::Integer` is different from the variable declared & defined inside `main`.

Comment: it's "buffalo buffalo buffalo.." garden path done in C++ way... only sentence roles in C++ are defined by scopes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is one of scope.

In the first example, both `Integer`s are declared in the global scope:

```
typedef int Integer;
Integer Integer = 1234;
```

In the second example, one is declared in the global scope, whereas the other is local to `main`:

```
typedef int Integer;
int main() {
    Integer Integer = 1234;
    ...
}
```

It works because, at the moment the compiler reads the first `Integer` inside `main`, there is only one entity with that name, so it must refer to the type in the global scope. But once you've declared a variable with the name `Integer` inside `main`, you cannot use that name again to refer to the type instead:

```
typedef int Integer;
int main() {
    Integer Integer = 1234; // OK because only the type is visible.
    Integer otherInteger = 567; // Error because Integer is a variable here.
    ::Integer thirdInteger = 89; // OK because :: resolves to the global one.
}
```